# How to identify what software installed MSSQL Express?

Tags: windows-10, sql-server-express

I noticed in Task Manager I'm running MSSQL Express and I don't remember which software it came with. Is there anyway to identify which software installed it so I can uninstall it, if I don't use that software anymore?

I looked into Windows Logs (Event viewer) but couldn't find anything useful.

The path is:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Binn
```

the Even viewer only show first occurrence in May 2019, and no details on which setup was used to install it.

Any ideas where to check?

Here is a screenshot of installed software on that date:

[image]

I assume it could be TFS or Visual Studio?

Comment: There is absolutely no way to determine what software installed MS SQL Express.  The best you can do is look at what software you installed on the same day, within Add/Remove Programs, please provide a screenshot of that information.  Determining what software you have installed, will allow anyone with enough knowlege about MS SQL Server, to determine what software installed it.  Without this information, your question, cannot be answered.

Comment: @Ramhound See attached screenshot, I assume it could be TFS or Visual Studio.

Comment: Visual Studio by default depending on what features you choose to install, will install whatever is the included version of MS SQL Server, but your screenshot doesn't indicate you have MS SQL Server 2012 Express installed, it indicates you have a full version of SQL Server 2012 which is installed by itself using it's own installer.  Of course I don't see Visual Studio 2013 installed either.

Comment: Why have you decided on this date?

Comment: @harrymc I installed all this software on that day, 5/26/2019.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my research, MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS is always mentioned for
SQL Express Server 2012.

Your only 2012 software is "Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (64-bit)", which I would
guess is the logical candidate.

I have installed SQL Server in the past (although maybe not the 2012 version),
and I remember that it also installs SQL Express,
although I would guess that this is used more for some of its
utilities rather than for direct use by SQL Server.

Comment: It makes sense. Since we are not sure, I don't want to remove it and corrupt anything. Right?

Comment: Agreed. I was in the same situation and made the same decision for my version at the time.